# How to reboot iPad that's stuck on lock screen with Siri/Search dialog up

Tags: ios, ipad, lockscreen

My iPad is stuck on the lock screen with the Search / Ask Siri dialog up. Holding Power + Home buttons does not shut it down, nor does the Vol-up / Vol-down / Vol-up trick I've read about. I can slide down the widgets (Remote, Brightness, etc.) but that's all. At the bottom of the screen it says **Press home to unlock**. Plenty of battery. How can I shut down or reboot or dismiss the search dialog?

Recent iPad, latest iOS (can't give you details because can't get to Home screen).

Comment: You said you were with the Siri dialog. Is Siri responding to what you say? If so, you could say "**Hey Siri, restart iPad**". Then, say "Yes" or tap the button "Restart".

Comment: @Thinkr - Tried that; Siri replies "You'll need to unlock your iPad first."

Comment: Also, have you tried swiping up from the bottom of your screen, it would normally ask you for the passcode.

Comment: A few things to try:  A) hold power for 20 seconds. B) Try using voice over.  If you can access Siri, say “turn on voice over” then see if you can enter your passcode.  C) using a USB adapter, try an external keyboard to enter the passcode

Comment: @Thinkr - I picked up the iPad a few minutes ago and it was prompting for my fingerprint, so perhaps I triggered that by unintentionally swiping up from the bottom, which I hadn't tried. I touchID'ed, and it immediately shutdown. When I powered back up the situation was cleared. I can't recreate the problem, I can only say something caused the ID prompt to eventually appear.

Comment: @Chap Glad it resolved itself!